# libfreetype-6.dll Missing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dll

I just compiled a Rust app using the stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu toolchain provided by rustup. Whenever I run the app from MSYS, it works fine, but running it any other way gives me a dialogue saying I'm missing lib-freetype-6.dll. I've installed freetype with GnuWin32, but I'm still getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the DLL [provided here](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/binaries/blob/master/x86_64/freetype.dll), and placing it in the project directory works perfectly.